# I can't seem to join these tables the way I want

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have two tables in Oracle, Table1 looks something like this:

```
Id_1 |  Id_1_Source  
23872 | 23870  
23873 | 23871  
23874 | 23872  
23875 | 23872  
23876 | 23873  
23877 | 23876  
23878 | 23877
```

Table2 looks like this:

```
Source | Color  
23870 | Yellow  
23871 | Green
```

What I would like is to show the color of all the Id_1 in Table1, but

```
SELECT Table1.Id_1, Table2.Color
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Id_1_Source = Table2.Source
```

isn't good enough. The problem is that the Id_1_Source sometimes relates to the Source in Table2, but also sometimes to another Id_1 in table1. The other Id_1 in table1 can also be related to the Source in Table2, but also to yet another Id_1 in table1. Eventually all Id_1 id's can be traced back to an Id_1_Source which exists as Source in Table2, but I have no idea how I can get that output through sql.

What I would like as result is as follows:

```
Id_1 | Color  
23872 | Yellow  
23873 | Green  
23874 | Yellow  
23875 | Yellow  
23876 | Green  
23877 | Green  
23878 | Green
```

I tried something with IF ... THEN or CASE, but I would have to do that multiple times and the amount of times needed could change over time, so I'm looking for another solution, perhaps make use of a LOOP somehow. Can someone please help?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you can use a recursive query:

```
with cte (id_1, id_1_source, lvl) as (
    select id_1, id_1_source, 1 lvl from table1
    union all 
    select c.id_1, t1.id_1_source, c.lvl + 1
    from table1 t1
    inner join cte c on t1.id_1 = c.id_1_source
)
select c.id_1, t2.color
from (select c.*, row_number() over(partition by id_1 order by lvl desc) rn from cte c) c
inner join table2 t2 on t2.source = c.id_1_source
where c.rn = 1
```

The idea is to use the recursive query to identify the `id_1_source` of the "top" record in the hierarchy tree that is represented by `table_1` for each `id_1`. You can then bring `table_2` with a `join`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=753f428941aa9a4517cd72becd557e45)**:

```
 ID_1 | COLOR 
----: | :-----
23872 | Yellow
23873 | Green 
23874 | Yellow
23875 | Yellow
23876 | Green 
23877 | Green 
23878 | Green
```

Comment: I have to read your answer a couple of more times to understand what you write, but it works 100%!! Thanks a lot!